# Can I use a TCS34725 color sensor with a LilyPad?

Tags: sensors

I have been trying to get a TCS34725 color sensor working with a LilyPad Arduino USB - ATmega32U4 board, but with no success. I am wondering if it possible?

I have been using the following sketch to try and get a reading but nothing appears in the monitor:

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>
#include "Adafruit_TCS34725.h"

/* Example code for the Adafruit TCS34725 breakout library */

/* Connect SCL    to analog 5
   Connect SDA    to analog 4
   Connect VDD    to 3.3V DC
   Connect GROUND to common ground */

/* Initialise with default values (int time = 2.4ms, gain = 1x) */
// Adafruit_TCS34725 tcs = Adafruit_TCS34725();

/* Initialise with specific int time and gain values */
Adafruit_TCS34725 tcs = Adafruit_TCS34725(TCS34725_INTEGRATIONTIME_700MS, TCS34725_GAIN_1X);

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  if (tcs.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Found sensor");
  } else {
    Serial.println("No TCS34725 found ... check your connections");
    while (1);
  }

  // Now we're ready to get readings!
}

void loop(void) {
  uint16_t r, g, b, c, colorTemp, lux;

  tcs.getRawData(&r, &g, &b, &c);
  // colorTemp = tcs.calculateColorTemperature(r, g, b);
  colorTemp = tcs.calculateColorTemperature_dn40(r, g, b, c);
  lux = tcs.calculateLux(r, g, b);

  Serial.print("Color Temp: "); Serial.print(colorTemp, DEC); Serial.print(" K - ");
  Serial.print("Lux: "); Serial.print(lux, DEC); Serial.print(" - ");
  Serial.print("R: "); Serial.print(r, DEC); Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print("G: "); Serial.print(g, DEC); Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print("B: "); Serial.print(b, DEC); Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print("C: "); Serial.print(c, DEC); Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.println(" ");
}
```

Comment: When really nothing appears on the serial monitor, then your serial connection doesn't work. Do you have selected the correct port and baud rate?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use TCS34725 Color Sensor with Lilypad?

Yes but please note that the I2C pins are D2 (SDA) and D3 (SCL). No extra components are required when connecting to the Adafruit TCS34725 breakout board. It contains pull-up resistors, and voltage/signal level converters (if needed).

Cheers!

Ref. https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/E-Textiles/Lilypad/Lilypad_Arduino_USB_v12.pdf